# Why does my service reinitialize?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

On my web application, I have a menu on the left that should be the same on all pages. On top of that, whenever a page changes, the item that was selected should be selected again when the new page loads. For this I made a directive:

**menu.html**

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-style="style()" fill-height="20">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="component-menu" ng-repeat="component in menu.components">
            <span>
                <img src="img/arrow_down_ok.png" />
                <span ng-class="{selected: menu.isActive(component.name)}" ng-click="menu.select(component.name,'all')" >{{ component.name }}</span>
            </span>
            <ul ng-if="component.devices">
                <li class="device-menu" ng-repeat="device in component.devices">
                    <span ng-class="{selected: menu.isActive(component.name, device.name)}" ng-click="menu.select(component.name,device.name)">{{ device.name }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**menu directive**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp.directives", ["services"]);

app.directive("componentMenu", ["menuService", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "js/templates/menu.html",
        controller: function($scope, $location, menuService) {
            var that = this;

            this.components = [ {
                name : "pms",
                devices : [ {name : "robot"}, {name : "controller"} ]
            }, {
                name : "bms",
                devices : [ {name : "ScanningController"}, {name : "nozzle"} ]
            }, ];
            console.log("menu components:", this.components);

            menuService.selectedComponent = "";
            menuService.selectedDevice = "";

            this.select = function(component, device) {
                device = device || "all";
                $location.search("component", component);
                $location.search("device", device);
                menuService.selectedComponent = component;
                menuService.selectedDevice = device;
                console.log("Menu selected:", menuService.selectedComponent + "/" + menuService.selectedDevice);
            }

            this.isActive = function(component, device) {
                device = device || "all";
                return component == menuService.selectedComponent && device == menuService.selectedDevice;
            }

            $scope.$watch(function($scope, that) {
                    return $location.url();
                }, function(url) {
                    if (url) {
                        var component = menuService.selectedComponent;
                        var device = menuService.selectedDevice;
                        if (!(menuService.selectedComponent == component && menuService.selectedDevice == device)) {
                            that.select(component, device);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

        },
        controllerAs: "menu",
    };
}]);
```

**menu service**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp.services", []);

app.factory("menuService", [function() {
    this._selectedComponent;
    this._selectedDevice;

    var menuSelection = {
            selectedComponent: this._selectedComponent,
            selectedDevice: this._selectedDevice
    }

    return menuSelection;
}]);
```

Whenever an item in the menu is selected, the console prints out the selected item correctly and next prints out the menu components (which seems correct since the URL gets changed). But when the page of the new URL is loaded, the variables inside the menu service are empty again.

Could anybody explain me why this is, as I understood that services were singletons and should keep their values.

Comment: Is your application developed as single page app?

Comment: Just to be clear , does `new page loads` mean using angular routing path change or new server side page?

Comment: @Sathish: No, there are multiple pages, but the menu should seemingly be a static component.

Comment: @charlietfl: I'm not sure, that part was written by someone else. Since it uses the $location, I assume angular routing?

Comment: Need to be sure, there is no state saving in javascript if you load a new server page. Is there an ngRoute or ui-router config for internal routing? You just told @Sathish it is not a single page app with routing so issue is now confusing

Comment: i think, you are trying to load two different angular app, hence you are getting this issue

Comment: I'm not yet that familiar with AngularJS. My appologies. There is a `$routeProvider` with several `when` statements loading a different html file depending on whatever comes after the first '/'

Comment: @Sathish: But if I use the same app name for both controllers, directives and services (in different js files) than the app gets overwritten. That is what the dependencies are for, not?

Comment: @charlietfl: It's a combination of both. But the issue also occurs when an element is selected in the menu and the URL after the `#` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using service,  it is instanciated with the new keyword which is why you bind the properties to the this and return a constructor. However you are using a factory.  In that case you create an object that you return. Therefore you need your components to be instanciated with var =.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but that didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Ok and is your service reinstanciated when you change url? (you can simply put a breakpoint)

Comment: No, the `this` statements are executed only on page load. Not when I select an element in the menu.

Comment: In your directive controller, you empty your service variables . When you change route if a new controller is instanciated it will empty the variable again.

Comment: Thank you! Your extra pair of eyes were very helpful for such an obvious mistake :)